# WMI query to Read 'Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL' C#

Tags: c#, wmi, wql

I have created an agent to read windows event using WMI. I ma using the agent from last 3 years to collect events. It is used in a SEIM product. The query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent where LogFile = 'System' or logFile='Active Directory Web Services'
```

I am able to get the events properly. But Now I want to read apploacker events 'Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL' (Application and Security Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> AppLocker -> Exe And DLL).

I tried the below query but it returns zero record though I have 40+ records in it. I can see the record in event viewer.

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent where LogFile = 'Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL'
```

I have tried with "wbemtest" but no record with no error.

I am not sure if this can be achieved by any other way using WMI. I know Powershell has a cmdlet and through which I am able to read 'Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL' events. But I want to read it using WMI.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance to all viewers.

Comment: Are you running as Administrator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the WMI Query parses the registry location `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog` for available event logs (see [MSDN Forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9ff438a-0486-4f8b-a908-102b8c473b2e/event-logs-from-windows-2008-r2-with-c?forum=netfxbcl)). 
Check the list you find there with the result of the query `Select * FROM Win32_NTEventLogFile`.

To add a logfile for WMI operations, add a new key under the above registry location with the name of the log ('Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL' in your case). Now it should return that log with your WMI query.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the PowerShell version, you could use the "Get-WinEvent" command to simplify what you're doing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent

Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-AppLocker/EXE and DLL"